# building with docker compose v2 fails but legacy docker-compose v1.29.2 and docker build succeed

Tags: docker, ulimit, docker-compose

I have this Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine/git as clone
WORKDIR /keycloak
RUN git clone https://github.com/maturbet-volta/nexus3-keycloak-plugin.git
WORKDIR /cargo
RUN git clone https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-cargo.git

FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine as build
WORKDIR /keycloak
COPY --from=clone /keycloak/nexus3-keycloak-plugin /keycloak
RUN mvn -PbuildKar package -Dmaven.test.skip=true

WORKDIR /cargo
COPY --from=clone /cargo/nexus-repository-cargo /cargo
RUN mvn -PbuildKar package
  
FROM sonatype/nexus3:latest
COPY --from=build /keycloak/target/*.kar /cargo/target/*.kar /opt/sonatype/nexus/deploy/
```

I have no problem building this Dockerfile with docker build or with docker-compose (v1.29.2) build

but when using docker compose version 2.16.0, it fails during the mvn package step with

```
library initialization failed - unable to allocate file descriptor table - out of memory
```

So I guess it is some kind of limit being hit, but I don't know how to change ulimits for docker compose build

So does anyone know how to configure docker compose v2 ?

thanks.

here is the output of docker info and docker compose version

```
$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.16.0
$ docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.16.0)

Server:
 Containers: 8
  Running: 3
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 5
 Images: 251
 Server Version: 20.10.23
 Storage Driver: btrfs
  Build Version: Btrfs v6.1.3
  Library Version: 102
 Logging Driver: journald
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: /usr/libexec/docker/docker-init
 containerd version: 
 runc version: 
 init version: 
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  selinux
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 6.1.18-200.fc37.x86_64
 Operating System: Fedora Linux 37 (Workstation Edition)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 31.06GiB
 Name: fedora
 ID: JJM4:AEWX:KYZS:3X54:B3GH:3ACD:JK7S:AK4R:CDT2:MT4C:BVHT:CNYK
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Registry Mirrors:
  https://registry.e.securiton.int/
 Live Restore Enabled: true
```

Comment: Please see [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually the issue was more that using `docker compose build`, the inherited  NOFILE limit was too big (infinity) which caused the old jdk-8 to try to reserve too much memory (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56895801/1737363).

Unfortunately `docker compose build` does not support the `--ulimit` parameter, so man needs to edit the docker systemd unit

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/10-limits.conf
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=65536
```

and then reload and restart the systemd unit

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

if you want to check what are the ulimits during a docker build you can use this Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine

RUN ulimit -a
```

and these commands

```
$ docker build . --no-cache --progress plain

$ docker-compose build --no-cache --progress plain

$ docker compose build --no-cache --progress plain

$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker compose build --no-cache --progress plain
```